# How to fix "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'" when use Task.Run

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin.forms but when I tried to use Task.Run in xamarin.Forms i get following error:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

My code so far :

```
 await Task.Run(async () =>
             {
                 await DoWork();
             });
```

I tried with :

```
 await Task.Run(async () =>
             {
                 await DisplayAlert("hi","hi","hi");
             });
```

but again same error

Comment: you need to look at the InnerException to determine the root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
await Task.Run(async() =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        // Not blocking main thread since it is still asynchronously called!!!
        await DisplayAlert("hi", $"", "hi");
    });

});
```

The error message says:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

You can not launch the DisplayAlert from a thread that is not the Main Thread! That is why you have to call either

```
await Task.Run(async() =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await DisplayAlert("hi", $"", "hi");  // Now launched from main thread!!!
    });

});
```

Or simply

```
await DisplayAlert("hi", $"", "hi"); // launched anyway from main thread.
```

In the more general case, what you want to avoid is modifying the UI from a thread that is not the main one, so if in "your" asynchronous method you are modifying the UI, you will have to do that from the main thread by calling

```
public async void DoWork()
{
    await DoHeaviWorkAsync();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        // Make changes to UI
    });
}
```

Comment: OK but when i use my method i need of creating with Task.Run

Comment: Could you share what is inside your method? Because Task.Run is not the problem itself. You can call for instance :  await Task.Run(async () =>
             {
                 await Task.Delay(1000); 
             });
And that will not throw any exception...

Comment: Because my UI is Blocking

Comment: I call Task.Run in button and when i call task.run in button event the program return me error above

Comment: Should i call task.run in button event